# Creating a bipartite graph in java

Tags: java, graph

I am new to programming and I need to create a bipartite graph from the matrix that i have. Most of the places that i have looked for has code for checking if the graph is bipartite or not. But none of them tell how to create it. Is there a way to do this in java?

the matrix is as follows:

```
     A1    A2    A3
B1    0     1     1
B2    1     0     1
B3    0     0     1
B4    0     1     0
```

Comment: How is creating a bipartite graph any different from creating any other graph? Are you looking for a particular data structure for bipartite graphs in particular?

Comment: http://users.skynet.be/alperthereal/source_files/html/java/Bipartite.java.html this is helpful for you

Comment: The link given by you shows how to check if the graph is bipartisan or not.